# imshow() function displays empty gray image. What do I do?

Tags: python, opencv

When I try to use `cv2.imshow()` it gives a shows the image for a second, then makes the window go gray. I can't seem to find anything about it, except that I should use `cv2.waitKey(0)`, which I am, and also to use `cv2.namedWindow()`. My code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

cv2.namedWindow('img')
img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Again, it shows the image for a second and then grays it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This code worked for me with the OpenCV 2.4.12 build that can be installed through dnf in Fedora 24.  What particular version of OpenCV are you using?  Did you compile it from scratch?

Comment: @Robert Prévost I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0. Also, I compiled it from scratch.

Comment: OpenCV 3.0.0 should be pretty similar to 2.4.12 in regards to this code.  I'll have to pull it and give it a try though.  In the meantime, my only other thought is that there is some problem with the runtime.  Maybe there are multiple versions of OpenCV or of some dependent library like libpython?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. check your sys.argv[1], try to replace with real path (i.e. "images/1.png")
2. destroyAllWindows() it is the function (use brackets)
3. parameter of waitKey (0 in your example) it is delay in ms, 0 means "forever", default value of delay is 0.
4. in fact you don't need namedWindow and destroyAllWindows here

try this:

```
import cv2
import sys

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: It was the image path that did it. Thanks