# opencv imshow shows an empty window when ran

Tags: python, opencv

when i try to use cv2.imshow() it gives me an empty window with the title i gave it. i tried another image with a link to the image, that did not work either. When i run `print(img.shape)` it gives me the size, so the image is loaded. here is my code:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

here is what i get when i run this script:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMay1.png)

if anyone knows something about this then please let me know!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [imshow() function displays empty gray image. What do I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563656/imshow-function-displays-empty-gray-image-what-do-i-do)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Your example, it should work. I would suggest to create minimal [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) with just opencv-python package installed and see if that works. You can also try to upgrade Your opencv to the most current version with `python3 -m pip install opencv-python --upgrade`.